# "On some days" vs "Some days"

Tags: prepositions

> **On** some days she is pretty lethargic; otherwise, she is super energetic.

Vs

> Some days she is pretty lethargic; otherwise, she is super energetic.

Is preposition *on* necessary?

Answer (score 1):

*On* really is only kinda-sorta needed if the pattern in the sentence is "On {X} {Y], on {X} {Z}" or similar.

> On some days she is pretty lethargic, on some other days she is super energetic.

It's worse to only use 1 *on* in the pattern above than using 0 or 2.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to emphasize that you also expanded the parallel structure she already had by changing otherwise to "[some] other days". I think that is the most important part to make the sentence more readable.